# How do I get `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` in my .inputrc to play nice with the Python interpreter?

Tags: bash, python, inputrc

I noticed that after I added the `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` line to my `~/.inputrc`, whenever I pressed tab to indent a block, it would show me the bash `Display all ... possibilities? (y or n)` prompt, and leave me unable to indent the actual code.

Is there any way to keep that line in my `.inputrc` but still have the tab key work as expected in the Python interpreter?

This is in my VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04 VM, if it matters.

**EDIT:** Curiously, I now have a different issue with the Python shell that comes with Django -- when I press tab, I get *Python* tab completion, but only with one Tab press. I've opened a separate question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/665323/why-is-the-python-interpreter-provided-by-django-showing-me-bash-tab-completion) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the conditional init constructs: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Init-Constructs.html#Conditional-Init-Constructs

I don't know your full setup, but I'm guessing you should probably try something like:

```
$if Bash
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
$endif
```